# Kibana: failed to load resource | error

Tags: javascript, apache, kibana

am getting the following error on my browser's debugger when i try to open Kibana :
do you have any idea what might me wrong ?

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server. (font-awesome.min.css, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server. (bootstrap.light.min.css, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server. (animate.min.css, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server. (require.js, line 0)
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require
    global code (require.config.js, line 4)
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require
    global code (index.html, line 1)
[Error] Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server. (timepicker.css, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server. (bootstrap-responsive.min.css, line 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue was with iptables, so :

```
iptables -F
```